# how to show picture and text in a label (PyQt)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I need to show a picture and text in a label, and this is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        pos = QPoint(50, 50)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawText(pos, 'hello,world')
        painter.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 255))

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = MyLabel()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('icon.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The label only display the text, and the picture is missing. 
How to display both image and text in the label.

Thanks for eyllanesc to solve this problem.

However, I have another two questions.

I found that if I display the image and text in the paintEvent of MyLable, likes:

```
def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
    super(MyLabel, self).paintEvent(QPaintEvent)

    pos = QPoint(50, 50)
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.drawText(pos, 'hello,world')
    painter.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 255))

    self.pixmap = QPixmap('C:\\Users\\zhq\\Desktop\\DicomTool\\icon.png')
    self.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
```

The text was display over the image even I firstly display the text and then display the image. Why?

Second, when I display the image and text in the paintEvent of MyLabel without the super(MyLabel, self).paintEvent(QPaintEvent), I found only the text is shown, and the picture is missing:

```
def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
    pos = QPoint(50, 50)
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.drawText(pos, 'hello,world')
    painter.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 255))

    self.pixmap = QPixmap('C:\\Users\\zhq\\Desktop\\DicomTool\\icon.png')
    self.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwriting the `paintEvent` method you have removed the behavior of displaying the `QPixmap` so the image is not visible. What you should do is first do what the `paintEvent` method of `QLabel` always does and then just paint the text.

```
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(MyLabel, self).paintEvent(event)
        pos = QPoint(50, 50)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawText(pos, 'hello,world')
        painter.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 255))
```

---

`QLabel` for reasons of optimization only updates the image if it is different for it uses the [`cacheKey()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#cacheKey) of `QPixmap`, so only draw when necessary.

In your first case the first time it is displayed, the text is painted, then you set the `QPixmap` and since no `QPixmap` is redrawn for the first time it calls `paintEvent()`, it draws the text again, then you set the `QPixmap` again but being the same as the previous one, I do not draw it but draw the one that is saved in the cache, so in the following times that `paintEvent()` is called, it only draws the text on the initial image of the cache.

In the second case, by not using the `paintEvent()` of the parent, the cache is not used, so the `QPixmap` will not be drawn and in that case only the text is drawn.

***Note***: it is not advisable to do a task other than drawing in the `paintEvent()` method, you could cause problems like an infinite loop.