# How to show picture and text in the label in the same time? (PyQt)

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel

I have a label (L1), and I want to show picture and text in L1. Then, I new a layout in the L1, and add a label (L2) in the layout. I draw text in the paintEvent of L1. The L2 can be moved around, and the L2 something will cover the text. A demo is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        label = QLabel('test')
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255)")
        layout.addWidget(label)


    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        super(MyLabel, self).paintEvent(QPaintEvent)
        pos = QPoint(50, 50)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawText(pos, 'hello,world')

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = MyLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The 'hello, world' is covered. How can I always display the text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show picture and text in a label (PyQt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137395/how-to-show-picture-and-text-in-a-label-pyqt)

Comment: Why do you place a QLabel inside another QLabel? the default widgets are not transparent so the child widget will cover the parent.

Comment: After placing a QLabel inside a QLabel, I can move the insided QLabel by setgeometry method. Because I have fulfill the sub-class, I want to find a method to solve this problem. Also, I have considered a alternate method that display both the text and image in one QLabel using drawImage and drawText in paint event respectively.

Comment: If you place a QLabel inside another QLabel using a layout, it will not help that you use setGeometry() since the position is controlled by the layout (that's the layout task) what are you trying to do? In your previous post you could already place the text and the image at the same time.

Comment: You are asking about an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), instead of asking what you want, please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few tutorials (and even SE posts) where a QLabel is used as a canvas for drawing things. If you start digging into the [Qt5 docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/index.html), they suggest that using QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene system is a good way to draw on a canvas. I won't lie: there is some overhead to figure out how to use everything together, but the system is pretty powerful and you can make pretty graphics this way from all kinds of primitives.

If you need something small and simple, using QLabel and PaintEvent is not bad. But if your app is going to do lots of graphics, I would recommend QGraphicsView.

Here's a simple example to draw two pieces of text on a QGraphicsView. For the first, we don't set the position, so it defaults to (0,0) the top left hand corner. The second is drawn at (50,50)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget,
                             QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, 
                             QGraphicsSimpleTextItem, QGridLayout)

import sys

class DemoApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(DemoApp, self).__init__()

        # set up the layout for the MainWindow. 
        grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.graphicsView = QGraphicsView()
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(grid_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)

        mytext1 = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem('the first label')
        scene.addItem(mytext1)

        mytext2 = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem('the second label')
        scene.addItem(mytext2)
        mytext2.setPos(50,50)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo_app = DemoApp(None)

demo_app.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There are a few examples for QGraphicsView that ship with PyQt5, most notably "dragdroprobot.py"